# Free Dynamic DNS Nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, dynamic-ip

I recently set up a server that I want to use as my primary hosting platform. So far, I've mapped some domains to it by setting up A records for them that point to my dynamic IP. As my IP can change randomly and without notice, however, I'm afraid of such downtime. Thus, I'm looking for a dynamic DNS solution.

So far, I've set up DynDNS, but I haven't found a way to use dynamic DNS with an existing domain. **Are there any free dynamic DNS nameserver services available?**

Comment: Your question's a bit unclear.  Can you rephrase?

Comment: I would work on hosting from a static ip address... No one that cares about uptime hosts on a dynamic ip anymore.. At least not a public dynamic ip..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of creating A records use CNAME records and point them to your Dyndns host.

So CNAME = WWW -> your.dyndns.addy

This covers your requirements and if you have configured dyndns to update automatically shouldn't require any further maintenance.

Comment: How should I configure my CNAME records?

Comment: Who is hosting DNS for your domains?

Comment: I'm currently using CloudFlare.

Comment: cool, thanks! I'm about to try that out, but first, a quick question: is it possible to do a similar thing but without a subdomain?

Answer (score 4):

I use http://freedns.afraid.org having using them for 2+ years without any problem. Disclaimer. I use it for home use and not production.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [DynDNS Custom](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/) web page says:

> Ability to update any hostname with dynamically changed IP address using standard update clients (Dynamic DNS feature for your domain).

so that appears to give you what you need.  Unfortunately it costs $29.95 a year, which is not free. :(

Comment: That looks like what I need, except it's not free. :( but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If its a single server, and main domain, [zonedit](http://www.zoneedit.com/) works great. I use wget and a custom upgrade script, but a good many common dynamic dns clients work too.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend https://duckdns.org/

Its free, simple and it works great.

The team behind it are not doing this for the money (although they would appreciate a donation) so the are no commercials and such.